# How to Reverse One Hot Encoded Values of my model predictions

Tags: pandas, keras, deep-learning

I turned my class labels to one hot encoded variables using pandas get dummies and i made my model predictions. The predictions are in one hot encoded form, how do i convert the predictions to the normal class vector

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    import keras
    from keras import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense


    df = pd.read_csv('./datasets/train.csv', header=0)
    data = pd.read_csv('./datasets/test.csv', header=0)

    """
    ==============================================
    preparing the training set
    ==============================================
    """

    df = df.drop(['ID_code'], axis=1)
    data_labels = data['ID_code']
    data = data.drop(['ID_code'], axis=1)

    """
    ==============================================
    preparing the test set
    ==============================================
    """

    y = df['target'].values
    y = pd.get_dummies(y) # oneHotEncode y
    X = np.delete(df.values, 0, axis=1)

    data = data.values

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=1000, activation='relu', input_dim=200))
    model.add(Dense(units=500, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=200, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    n_epochs = 5

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=1000, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

    # now to predict the classes of the output
    predictions = model.predict(data)
```

how do i get predictions to be changed back into the original form of y.

Comment: The dup target should get you started.

Comment: thank you for replying. but it throws an error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'argmax'
let me edit the question to post my whole code.

Comment: I've still not been able to solve it. Tried a lot of ways to relate the dup to mine but all have been to no avail

Comment: it has been solved now with [i for i in x.argmax(1)]